# AWS Launch sample webite in docker on ec2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ansible

I need some help deploying a simple website in docker in ec2 instances using ansible.
currently, I have a playbook that provision an ec2 instance but I want to be able to install docker and apache server and deploy a simple website. for instance, just a simple webpage that says hello just so I know it is working. I am not sure how to going about doing this

```html
- name: deploy Ec2 Instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: Launch ec2 instance
    ec2:
      instance_type: t2.micro
      key_name: mykeypair
      image: ami-00eb20669e0990cb4
      region: us-east-1
      group: default
      count: 1
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-ed43648a
      wait: yes
```

Comment: You say docker but where is the docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following veeery simplified approach should fit your needs:

**EDIT** (for this apache example there's no need for a custom Dockerfile)!

You can reference apache within a docker-compose.yml file (this has to be located within the files or templates directory relative to your playbook file):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:2.4-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Add these tasks to your play:

```
# you probably have to create your Docker Directories first and check for existence of your files on the host

...

- name: "transfer dockerfiles for service"
  template:
    src: docker-compose.yml
    dest: "/home/ec2-user/deploy/apache/docker-compose.yml"
    mode: 0755
    trim_blocks: no

- name: "(re)start service"
  shell: |
    cd /home/ec2-user/deploy/apache
    docker-compose up --build -d
```

After completion of this playbook run you can simply curl localhost/index.html on the host itself.